# Is there a way to limit published fields in Meteor aldeed tabular package

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, datatable

is there a way to limit what data is published to an aldeed tabular datatable? For example, if my collection has attributes A, B, C, D, attribute C is very sensitive and therefore I want to prevent it from being published, so only attributes A, B, D are published to the datatable. I checked the documentation but could not find an explicit answer to this...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `autopublish package`.

and you should [limit field to return from a query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), in this case on the [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) function.

```
Meteor.publish('dataTable',function(){
  return Data.find({}, { fields: { A: true, B: true, C: false, D: true } });
}
```

And simply [Subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) to that publish

```
Meteor.subscribe('dataTable')
```

NOTE: if you have the collection on the `/lib` folder, be sure to make the `Subscribe` reactive with

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
 Meteor.subscribe('dataTable')
})
```